# curl https://SERVER_IP:8443 works on Mac but not when I SSH into server

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Via terminal on a Mac (PHP 7.1.23), I can issue a curl (curl 7.54.0) command via the CLI such as:

```
curl https://www.SERVER_HOSTNAME:8443
```

and it works without error.

I SSH into the VPS Linux server running x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu with curl 7.61.1 and PHP 7.3.5 and if I do a curl command without the port:

```
curl https://www.SERVER_HOSTNAME
```

it works fine but as soon as I add the port it chokes.

```
curl https://www.SERVER_HOSTNAME:8443
```

gives this error:

> "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
>   More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

The actual certificate is not self signed. It is via Godaddy with a Bundle and a good CA.

Any suggestions on what I need to fix or set?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the `-k` option to disable certificate checking.

Comment: Never disable certificate checking. You might as well use plain text HTTP then.

Comment: Your title is inconsistent with the body of your question: SERVER_IP or SERVER_HOSTNAME? That will not impact the answer but it is still an inconsistency

Comment: "Any suggestions on what I need to fix or set?" Install the CA everywhere you need it. This is what the error message tells you: the CA is unknown

Comment: I ask the question here because I am using PHP to program something and I use the CLI to verify some syntax. The code was blowing up even though I was explicitly giving the path to the certificates . . . the issue is things work great in one context . . . partially in another . . .and with an error when I attach the port number. If it works in two out of three the question remains why not in the third . . .